# Tabela de produtos no Ionic 3 - Css

Tags: html, css, ionic, ionic3, ionic2

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com um probleminha e até agora fiz várias pesquisas, mas não encontrei uma resposta satisfatória. Como faço para desenvolver uma tabelinha de produtos, nesse estilo :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a dúvida, mais especificamente? Você quer saber como exibir uma tabela usando somente CSS? Ou está com dúvida em alguma característica específica dessa tabela da imagem? Por favor, poste o que já tem hoje, HTML e CSS, se tiver.

Answer (score 0):

seu-arquivo.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>Seu Título</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid no-padding>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>Entrada</ion-col>
        <ion-col>Saída</ion-col>
        <ion-col>Tempo</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <div *ngFor="let item of lista">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>{{ item.descricao }}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{ item.qtd_valor }}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{ item.total }}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </div>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

seu-arquivo.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({ name: 'page-suaPagina' })
@Component({
  selector: 'page-sua',
  templateUrl: 'sua.html',
})
export class SuaPage {

  lista = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.lista = [
      {descricao:'Carne 1,5kg',qtd_valor:'1 x 22,95',total: 22,95},
      {descricao:'Tomate Vermelho 0,5kg',qtd_valor:'0,5 x 5,00',total: 2,25}
    ];
  }

}
```